# How to get the first row and the last row while taking also any row that come after number of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a data-set and i need to take the first row and the last row and each row that come after 3 rows,

[image: 20 rows]

i tried

```
SELECT  v, t
FROM (
        SELECT *,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t) AS rown
        FROM "table"
    ) AS "skippedResult"
WHERE mod(rown, 3) = 1
```

but the result return is

[image]

so how to make sure to select the first row and the last row and each row after 3 rows for example, many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem pretty close:

```
SELECT v, t
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t ASC) AS seqnum,
             row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t DESC) AS seqnum_d
      FROM "table" t
     ) "skippedResult"
WHERE mod(seqnum, 3) = 2 OR 1 IN (seqnum, seqnum_d)
```